# Unable to download praw using pip

Tags: python, praw

I'm currently working my way through [this](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/getting_started.html) guide which details how to make a reddit bot. followed the first step and ran my code in Python IDLE but had an issue because I didn't have PRAW downloaded.

*My question* is how exactly do I download PRAW? I looked around and tried downloading it through a few methods but none of them seemed to work for me. Currently working my way through [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHes-Cdmfzc) method but I keep getting an error:
Fatal error in launcher. Unable to create process using...

Comment: Can you show us the error?
Also , why didn't the "last methods" didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

1. Download the zip from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/praw#downloads
2. Unzip.
3. python setup.py install